# how to execute the tasks which are having matching tag when calling that role in ansible?

Tags: ansible, tags, roles

I want to skip the tasks which are having a specific tag

example task inside a role which i want to skip:

```
- name: restart testsvc
  service: 
   name: testsvc
   state: restarted
  tags: 
  - primary
```

The main playbook where i'm calling the role is as below

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
  - vars/all.yml
  roles:
  - { role: setup, --skip-tags: "primary", when: jenkins_standby is defined }
```

But it is not working.Is it possible to handle this in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting or skipping a specific tag should be specified on the command line when you run your playbook.

```
ansible-playbook play.yml --skip-tags "primary"
```

`skip_tags` option, which is set by the command line options very early, is used in initial parsing of the playbook.

[Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#selecting-or-skipping-tags-when-you-run-a-playbook)

Defining `skip_tags` option from within the playbook does not throw any parse error, however it's too late to be of any use since the playbook is already parsed.